# Постраничная навигация wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В магазине на woocommerce стоит постраничная навигация для кастомной страницы категории. Плагин wp-pagenavi (плагин не имеет значения, даже без плагина чистым кодом - работает всегда одинаково). 
**Выборка товаров у меня осуществляется вот так**

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_key' => '_price',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => $order_date,
'product_cat' => $category_ID,
'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => 'vid',
                'value' => $vid,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ))
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'Товаров не найдено' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    wp_pagenavi();
```

Как видно из кода, товары делятся по 12 штук на страницу и разбиваются на странице. Но пользователь на странице может выбрать чтобы выводилось не 12 товаров на страницу, а 16 например. Я меняю posts_per_page на 16, на странице отображаются 16 товаров, **НО** страниц так же остается 13! При этом последние естественно становятся пустыми **(125 товаров, 16 товаров на страницу = 8 страниц. вот так будет правильно)**

**Вопрос:** можно ли связать **любую постраничную навигацию для кастомной страницы** категории магазина woocommerce, чтобы при подсчете количества страниц учитывался параметр **posts_per_page**? И как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось все очень просто

```
wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop ));
```